# Multiple functions for eventListener Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have this html table and span. I am trying to make it so that on each row value1 and value2 will add together and display in the sum cell in the same row. Also so that each value for value1, value2, and Sum in both row 1 and in row 2 will add together and display in the span for that specific column.

I know for the rows it would be easy, but can I have multiple functions for the JavaScript event listeners on a single element, one would do the calculation for the column and the other would do the calculation for rows. Or should I be using a library (eg. knockoutJS)

```
<table style="border: 1px solid">
    <thead style="border: 1px solid">
        <th>
            Value 1
        </th>
        <th>
            Value 2
        </th>
        <th>
            Sum
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td id="r1c1">
            <input style="width:50px" />
        </td>
        <td id="r1c2">
            <input style="width:50px" />
        </td>
        <td id="r1c3">
            <span id="r1Sum">0</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="r2c1">
            <input style="width:50px"/>
        </td>
        <td id="r2c2">
            <input style="width:50px"/>
        </td>
        <td id="r2c3">
            <span id="r2Sum">0</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    Value 1 column total: <span id="val1ColTotal">0</span>
    &nbsp;
    Value 2 column total: <span id="val2ColTotal">0</span>
    &nbsp;
    Sum column total: <span id="sumColTotal">0</span>
```

JSFIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/gauldivic/4002h1wj/2/

Comment: you can add as many events as you'd like to any element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- calling 2 functions (with calculations and ui update) from the event listener callback
- works with n-number of rows

https://jsfiddle.net/13e1kzm3/

---

```
 <td>
    <input style="width:50px" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input style="width:50px" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <span id="sum">0</span>
  </td>
```

---

```
function sumRows(){
   $('tr').each(function() {
     var sum = 0;
     $(this).find('input').each(function() {
       sum += +parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
     });
     $("#sum", this).text(sum);
   });
}

function sumColumns(){
 //...
}

$("table").bind("keyup", function() {
  sumRows(this);
  sumColumns(this);
});
```

---

- multiple event listeners can be added to the element (using jquery)

---

```
$("table").bind("keydown, keyup", function() {...
```

Comment: is  sumRows(this); sending the whole table or that specific row?

Comment: Would it probably be a better idea for me to assign the id to the actual input instead of the td? I'm leaning towards yes.

Comment: for it is only triggering on click and none of the keyboard presses

Comment: its dynamic lol, this should help though. its part of a timesheet app.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged `Knockout` on your question ,here is an example of using the power of knockout to do what you want easier 
Example : https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/188/

Html :

```
<body> 
<table style="border: 1px solid">
    <thead style="border: 1px solid">
        <th>
            Value 1
        </th>
        <th>
            Value 2
        </th>
        <th>
            Sum
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach:TableItems">
       <tr>
       <td data-bind="text:$index()+1"></td>
        <td >
            <input style="width:50px" data-bind="textInput:Value1"/>
        </td>
        <td >
            <input style="width:50px" data-bind="textInput:Value2"/>
        </td>
        <td >
            <span id="r1Sum" data-bind="text:RowTotal"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>


</table>
    <div>
       <span>Number of row(s):</span><span data-bind="text:TableItems().length"></span>
   </div> 
   <div>
       <span>Value 1 column total:</span><span data-bind="text:Column1">0</span>
   </div> 
   <div>
     <span> Value 2 column total: </span><span data-bind="text:Column2">0</span>
  </div> 
  <div>
    <span>Sum column total:</span><span data-bind="text:Column3"></span>
   </div> 
   <input type="button" value="Add New Row" data-bind="click:AddRow"/>
```

VM :

```
var TableItemViewModel = function (data){
   var self = this;
   self.Value1 = ko.observable(data.value1);
   self.Value2 = ko.observable(data.value2);
   self.RowTotal = ko.computed(function () {
     return parseInt(self.Value1()? self.Value1() : 0) + parseInt(self.Value2()?self.Value2() :0);
   });

}
    function MainViewModel() {
    //Sample data
    var obj = [{value1 : 1 , value2 :11  },{value1 : 2 , value2 :22  }];

        var self = this; 
        self.TableItems = ko.observableArray([]);
                self.TableItems($.map(obj, function (item) {
             return new TableItemViewModel(item);
             }));
        self.Column1 = ko.computed(function () {
            var sum  = 0 ; 
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.TableItems(), function (item) {
                 sum =  sum + parseInt(item.Value1()) ;
            });
          return sum;
        });
          self.Column2 = ko.computed(function () {
            var sum  = 0 ; 
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.TableItems(), function (item) {
                 sum =  sum + parseInt(item.Value2()) ;
            });
          return sum;
        });
        self.Column3 = ko.computed(function () {
            var sum  = 0 ; 
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.TableItems(), function (item) {
                 sum =  sum + parseInt(item.RowTotal()) ;
            });
          return sum;
        });
        self.AddRow = function (){
            self.TableItems.push(new TableItemViewModel({value1 : 1 , value2 :1  }))
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings( new MainViewModel);
```

Comment: what about n-number of rows?

Comment: Number of rows is length of the `observableArray`. Also , I added an `Add New Row` button into the example for dynamic  use, So you can add a new row and everything is bound.